# Google search result pages no longer show number of matchings?

Tags: google-search

Google search result pages no longer show number of matchings? I used to use that as a hint to how popular/regular a word combination is compared to its variants.

[image]

Comment: We can’t explain why Google has chosen to do this and if there is a way around it.

Comment: Google (AU) on windows 11 through MS Edge is still providing a counter of results for me. I get 1.44m results for your search term.
Perhaps its related to your OS, browser/settings, or region? Consider any deployed settings if you're using a business-controlled machine or account logged into the browser too.